# Scatter plot color by variable

Tags: stata, scatter-plot

I want to make an scatter plot in Stata with points colored according to a categorical variable.

The only way I've found to do this, is to code colors in layers of a twoway plot.

However, this seems a rather convoluted solution for such a simple operation:

```
twoway (scatter  latitud longitud if nougrups4 ==1, mcolor(black)) ///
       (scatter  latitud longitud if nougrups4 ==2, mcolor(blue))  ///
       (scatter  latitud longitud if nougrups4 ==3, mcolor(red))  ///
       (scatter  latitud longitud if nougrups4 ==4, mcolor(green))
```

Is there a simpler and automatic way to do this?

In this case, the categorical variable `nougrups4` came from a cluster analysis. A general solution would be fine, but also a specific solution to draw clusters.

Comment: You could create a wrapper program for the `twoway scatter` command to do this automatically.

Comment: I suppose I could. However I want to confirm that there is not a simple built in solution to do it that I'm missing. Other statistical packages (simpler and cheaper than Stata) have that feature. For example, I remember using it in Statgraphics, R (both base graphics and ggplot2) and even RCommander. Even in Excel you can plot an scatterplot with categories as colors.

Comment: I am not sure what is so complicated about the above syntax. In any case i provide a simple example in my answer below.

Comment: In general different colo[u]rs may not work well and it's better to think in the first instance of different point or marker symbols. Your own tentative code uses both red and green but it is, or should be, well known that many people find it difficult to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do this by hand:

```
sysuse auto, clear

separate price, by(rep78)
tw scatter price? mpg
drop price?
```

Or in one line using Nick Cox's `sepscatter` command from SSC:

```
sepscatter price mpg, separate(rep78)
```

The latter command can also output other type of plots with the `recast()` option.

Comment: `sepscatter` is from SSC and free (although donations to the author of citations and libations are welcome).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a 'simpler' built-in solution for what you want to do.

However, here's a simple wrapper command, which you can extend to meet your needs:

```
capture program drop foo
program define foo 

syntax varlist(min=1 max=3) 

quietly {
    tokenize `varlist'
    levelsof `3', local(foolevels) 

    local i = 0
    local foocolors red green blue

    foreach x of local foolevels {
        local ++i
        local extra `extra'  || scatter `1' `2' if `3' == `x', mcolor("`: word `i' of `foocolors''")
    }           
    twoway `extra' 
}
end
```

And a toy example:

```
clear
set obs 10

generate A = runiform()
generate B = runiform()
generate C = .

replace C = 1 in 1/3
replace C = 2 in 4/7
replace C = 3 in 8/10

foo A B C
```